# How do I make an package of an standalone app in VS.NET?

Tags: deployment, installation

So here is the situation.  I want to bundle Google Chrome Portable by itself.  The only modification I would make is to change the default homepage, and add a shortcut link to the desktop.  I also can't use the included Google Chrome installer because I would need to change the default homepage.

What should I use to make a simple installer that just unzip the Google Chrome folder into programs and create the shortcut on desktop?  I don't need anything fancy like program registration or anything like that, in fact, most of my clients probably will not have installation rights on there computer.

Now my project is in Visual Studio 2008, but I am willing to use any other type of packager.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the [free version of Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html), i.e. by creating a "**Simple**" project. [There is also a five-minutes tutorial](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html) on how to create the package

Answer (score 0):

I went with the WinRar SFX Archive File, with auto-run after it finishes.